# How to pass List<model> to controller in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 model : Question and Answer such as below, I want to send a List model to View, and when submit form, i submit List model to controller, but in Action UpdateQuestion a can only get the list of question but the list of answer was not. Can you explain and show me how to get list answer of each question when i submit form

```
public class Question
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("QuestionType")]
        public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Field")]
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public virtual Field Field { get; set; }

        public string Brief { get; set; }

        public bool IsGroup { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("QuestionGroup")]
        public int? QuestionGroupId { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }

        public int Priority { get; set; }

        public int Order { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }
```

and:

```
public class Answer
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength]
        public string Content { get; set; }      

        [ForeignKey("Question")]      
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }      

        public float Mark { get; set; }

        public int Priority { get; set; }    
    }
```

I have controller Index to passing a list of Question to View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var listQuestion = db.Questions.ToList();
return View(listQuestion);
}
```

[HttpPost]

```
        public ActionResult UpdateQuestion(string submit, List<Question> Questions)
        {
        ...

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And In View :

```
@model List<Question>
@{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateQuestion", "TestRoom")) 
{ 
     <ul>
         @foreach(var question in Model)//Question
         {                                
              <li>
              @Html.Hidden("Questions["+i+"].Id", question.Id)
              @{i++;}
              @Html.Raw(question.Brief)
              <ul>
                   @foreach (var answers in question.Answers)
                   {                                            
                        <li>@Html.RadioButton("Questions["+i+"]_Answers["+j+"]",answers.Id)                                                
                                                @Html.Raw(answers.Content)

                                                @{j++;}
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                        @{j = 0;}
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            }

                        </ul>
                        <div class="aq-button-panel">
                            <button type="submit" value="Finish" name="submit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Submit</button>
                            <button type="submit" value="Back" name="submit">Go Next <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" value="Next" name="submit">Go Back <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>                        
                        </div>
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with you code. First you cannot bind a radio button to a complex object (in your case `Answer` because a radio button group only posts back a single value (in your case the `id` value of the selected `Answer`). Next you loops are generating radio buttons groups that would be attempting to bind the selected answer to only the first answer which makes no sense (your setting the value of `j` to `0` each time). Your model needs a property to bind to (say) `int SelectedAnswer`.

Start by creating view models that represent what you want to display/edit in your view (add display and validation attributes as required)

```
public class AnswerVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Brief { get; set; }
  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<AnswerVM> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

In your get method, get your data models and map then to the view models and return `IEnumerable<QuestionVM>` to the view.

Next create an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `QuestionVM` (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/QuestionVM.cshtml`)

```
@model QuestionVM
<li>
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Brief)
  <ul>
    @foreach(var answer in Model.PossibleAnswers)
    {
      <li>
        <label>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedAnswer, answer.ID, new { id = "" })
          <span>@answer.Content</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
</li>
```

and in the main view

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionVM>
....
@Html.BeginForm(...))
{
  <ul>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m) // this will generate the correct html for each question in the collection
  </ul>
  <div class="aq-button-panel">
    <button type="submit" ... />
    ...
  </div>
}
```

and change the POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateQuestion(string submit, IEnumerable<QuestionVM> model)
```

The model now contains the ID of each question and the ID of the selected answer for each question.

Note that if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, you will need to repopulate the `PossibleAnswers` property of each question (your not generating a form control for each property of each `Answer` in each `Question` - and nor should you) so the `PossibleAnswers` property will be an empty collection when you submit the form)

Comment: Thank you so much, I made it.But another question, if a question have more than one answer.So can you tell me, how to do that ?

Comment: In that case your `AnswerVM` model would have an additional property `bool IsSelected` and then create an `EditorTemplate` for `AnswerVM` which would have a hidden input for the `ID` and a checkbox bound to the `IsSelected` property. Inside `QuestionVM`, replace the `@foreach` that generates the radio buttons with the `@EditorFor(m => m.PossibleAnswers)` which will now generate a checkbox for each answer. Note the `int SelectedAnswer` is no longer required.

Comment: If on the other hand you want to have different types of questions where some are multiple choice (i.e. radio buttons), some allow just a text answer, some allow Yes/No answers etc, then you need a series of different view models - say `MultipleChoiceQuestionVM`, YesNoQuestionVM` etc and then you main model would have collections of these (say) `QuestionaireVM` that contains `List<MultipleChoiceQuestionVM>` etc.

Comment: I do not have the time to write your application for you :). Ask a new question with the code you have tried and explaining what your wanting to achieve and whats not working. I and others will be happy to help.